# How to retrieve tag's content using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to capture the value `179` in a variable

```
<span class="robux " data-se="item-privatesale-price">179</span>
```

How can I do this using JQuery in the console?

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery installed? Use `typeof jQuery` and it should return `"function"`

Answer (score 3):

Use the class selector of jQuery

```
$(".robux").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = $('.robux').text()
```

That should work

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to search API of jquery.
[Here is a link](http://api.jquery.com/text/) about a method of text();